# How to use Dynamic Variables?

Tags: excel, variables, dynamic, vba

Alright what did I do wrong? Found this on the web, tried it and got a type mismatch. Just trying to make my code more concise by having the variables define themselves, for e.g. Y(10), Y(11), Y(12), Y(13), or Y10 ... Y13, so I'll have 4 variables at the end of the sub. Y10-13 are NOT the cell positions, but they are related. Look Below!

[image: the Actual Dataset]

variable a refers to the actual row, so say Y10 = 400 is the only entry on row 5, row 7 has Y10 = 7 and Y12 = 3. I did not define this in the code because this section runs as function(a) and a is defined before the function itself such that the sub checks for a=1 to the last row.

```
Dim Y(10 To 13) As Integer 'these are just variables
Dim a as long 'this is an arbitrary row number defined before the function

For I = 10 to 13 'These are column numbers in the actual data range

If .Worksheets("15SK").Cells(a, I) <> "" Then
    Y(I) = .Worksheets("15SK").Cells(a, I).value 'Y(I) basically takes the value of the cell (a,I)
End If

Next
```

I basically need a dynamic variable Y(I) or YI (in any form really) because later sections of my code calls for it. I'll share another section to state my point, but its difficult for me to translate what I'm doing in this next section:

```
For I = 10 To .Worksheets("15SK").Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 'All models

    If .Worksheets("15SK").Cells(a, I) <> "" Then 'If product model order > 0
    'removed a section of code here

        j = j + 3 'step 3
If ItemType = "Adaptor" And Y > X1 And DUP <> 1 Then

            Y1 = Y1 + Y(I)

                If ItemType = "Adaptor" And Y1 > X1 Then 'adding another duplicate

                    DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 3) = .Worksheets("15SK").Cells(2, I) 'First DO product model row
                    DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j - 1, 1) = Y1 - X1 'Excess Qty to be charged
                    DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j - 3 - 1, 1) = Y(I) - (Y1 - X1) 'Making the previous row's Qty FOC by no. of CD - no. of previous
                    DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j - 1, 2) = "pcs"
                    DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j - 1, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(DOwb.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, 3), .Worksheets("Catalogue").Range("catalogue"), 2, False) 'Model Description
                    JFOC = j
                    j = j + 3 'step 3
                    DUP = 1 'stops the duplication

                ElseIf Y1 = X1 Then
                    JFOC = j
                End If
            Y1 = 0
        End If
```

Sorry guys really new to VBA, or coding for the matter. Terrific help so far!

Comment: This is called *Array*.  You can search by this term.

Comment: What is *a* ? You've declared it and then used it without giving it a value.

Comment: My bad fellows, this is a small section of the code I'm doing. a is defined way before the function.

Comment: If you are looking to put the value of cell Y10 into the Y(10) variable array element then *a* should be 25 and you have the row and column parameters backwards in `.Cells`.

Comment: I'm guessing you are trying to stuff a string, boolean or error into your array of integers. Check the nature of the worksheet values you are assigning to the array.

Comment: I messed up the question, I'm trying to create a 'dynamic' variable, Y(I) <--- where I can be 10, 11, 12, 13 or 14 which I can call up later in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Y10 cannot be the name of variable (because it could be confused with cell Y10). Code that attempts to use such variable names will not work. Try other name, for example y_10 will be fine.